# How to set method to some storage and call it later in android studio

Tags: java, android, uuid

I am learning java and i am using Uuid to create ID for customers in my app and i would like to know how to store this code

```
Private static String formEventUuid; 
public static void sendStatistic1()
{
formEventUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

And call it in another statistic2 to get the same ID.

```
public static void sendStatistic2()
{
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at the storage options that Android provide and pick one that is suitable for you: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` for this.